# How to extract data as a List from Set with dynamic keys in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have below set in terraform (which is extracted from data module)

```
{
   key1 {
     id = "5"
     name = "A"
   },
   key2 {
     id = "6"
     name = "A"
   }
}
```

keys are dynamic, and it will be `n` number of them, any value.

How can I get the below result? Please notice it's List of strings

```
[
  "5",
  "6"
]
```

I tried below, but it says `Unsupported attribute`

```
output "email_channels_keys" {
  value = var.emails.*.id
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `for` lambda expression to iterate on the `map(object))` and extract the value for the `id` key in the `object` within each `map`:

```
output "email_channels_keys" {
  value = [ for key, value in data.data_name.block_name.attribute : value.id ]
}
```

We use a `list` constructor to instantiate the type as a `list`. We then iterate over the `map` and store the `string` key in the temporary lambda scope variable `key`, and the `object` value in the temporary lambda scope variable `value`. We then access the value of the `id` key within the object with the normal usage of `.id` (`["id"]` is also valid syntax, but conventionally `map` values are accessed with `["<key>"]` and object values with `.<key>` syntax). The returned value is assigned to `email_channels_keys` in your outputs.

Note that for your specific use case, you will need to update the `data` namespace for your specific data that you reference at the beginning of the question, and you may want to update `key` and `value` variables for more specific names.